# Does java immutable list actually mean non-resizable?

Tags: java, collections

Surprisingly the code:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2);
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue));
System.out.println(list); // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Doesn't throw `UnsupportedOperationException` in my code. But the list is modified.

So my question is: am I doing something wrong or `immutable` can be modified? It cannot be resized though.(so isn't the better name for this non-resizable?)

**Edit:** immutable of course

Comment: Question is: where do you get "unmodifiable" from? It's not in your source code. Are you relating to the description if `Arrays.asList();`?

Comment: Sorry, immutable of course

Comment: Same question: where do you get the notion of "immutable" from? It's not in your source code. Are you relating to the description if Arrays.asList();?

Comment: Yes, I got it from `Arrays.asList()` what was wrong

Comment: The list mutable *and* it allows modifying the array you’ve passed to `asList` that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `List` is mutable in java so it can be changed,this means we can change an item in a list by accessing it directly as part of the assignment statement.
If you want to make an unmodifiable List you should check  `public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list) {` method from `Collections` class

Here is an example

```
 List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2); // you have created a mutable List
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue));
        System.out.println(list); // prints [1, 2, 3]


        List<Integer> list2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

        list2.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue));
        System.out.println(list); // throws UnsupportedOperationException
```

---

And yes they are `non-resizable` if we try to add a new value in our unmodifiableList it will throw  `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
list2.add(3);// throws UnsupportedOperationException
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` does not say anything about "immutable" or "unmodifiable". It only states that the list is fixed-size. You can still change elements, but you cannot add any, as the list would have to be resized. @Typhon's answer gives you good details on immutability.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class FixedSize {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final List<String> fsl = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
        System.out.println("List before change: " + fsl.size());
        for (final String i : fsl) {
            System.out.println("\t" + i);
        }

        try { // this will fail
            fsl.add("1");
            System.out.println("Did not fail for some strange reason");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Fails as expoected");
        }


        fsl.set(1, "LOL");

        System.out.println("List after change: " + fsl.size());
        for (final String i : fsl) {
            System.out.println("\t" + i);
        }
    }
    
}
```